# Formatting a Duration like HH:mm:ss

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a good way to format a Duration in something like hh:mm:ss, without having to deal with time zones?

I tried this:

```
DateTime durationDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(0);
String duration = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss').format(durationDate);
```

But I always get 1 hour to much, in this case it would say `01:00:00`

And When I do this:

```
Duration(milliseconds: 0).toString();
```

I get this: `0:00:00.000000`

Comment: FYI, your approach didn't work because despite your variable names, you didn't compute *durations*.  `durationDate` is a `DateTime`; it's a point in time and therefore is subject to an adjustment from UTC into your local time zone.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You can use `Duration` and implement this method:

```
String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
  String negativeSign = duration.isNegative ? '-' : '';
  String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
  String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).abs());
  String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).abs());
  return "$negativeSign${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
}
```

Usage:

```
final now = Duration(seconds: 30);
print("${_printDuration(now)}");
```

Comment: Thanks thats some clean dart. Do you know what the problem with my 1st approach was?

Comment: Just check the doc and you will understand : https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html

Comment: If you want to make it shorter: `String twoDigits(int n) => n >= 10 ? "$n" : "0$n";`

Comment: Or just `n.toString().padLeft(2, "0")`.

Comment: @diegoveloper Thanks dear, I have improved it by adding a condition on hour, minute and second so that if file does not have hours then show only minutes and seconds part eg. 10:20 (minutes:seconds) instead of 00:10:20 (hour:minutes:seconds). Thanks again.

Comment: getAudioDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    List<String> output = [];
    if(duration.inHours > 0){
      output.add(twoDigits(duration.inHours).toString());
    }
    if(int.parse(twoDigitSeconds) > 0){
      output.add(twoDigitMinutes);
      output.add(twoDigitSeconds);
    }
    return output.join(':');
  }

Comment: `_printDuration` might not be the best name since you are just returning a string rather than printing it. Perhaps _durationToString would be better. You could also add it as an extension by the way.

Answer (score 65):

You can start creating a format yourself, come on this one:

```
String sDuration = "${duration.inHours}:${duration.inMinutes.remainder(60)}:${(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60))}";
```

Comment: duration.inMinutes is the total number of minutes, for example if the duration is 2 hours the minutes will be 120

Comment: Hey, thanks. I didn't know it was over 60 minutes. I trust your answer. For this I found the remainder method inside the library and introduced it to limit it up to 60.

Comment: Works great but you lose the leading zeros, if you want to keep them just add `.toString().padLeft(2, '0')` for each concerned data (hours, minutes, seconds)

Answer (score 46):

The shortest, most elegant and reliable way to get `HH:mm:ss` from a `Duration` is doing:

```dart
format(Duration d) => d.toString().split('.').first.padLeft(8, "0");
```

Example usage:

```dart
main() {
  final d1 = Duration(hours: 17, minutes: 3);
  final d2 = Duration(hours: 9, minutes: 2, seconds: 26);
  final d3 = Duration(milliseconds: 0);
  print(format(d1)); // 17:03:00
  print(format(d2)); // 09:02:26
  print(format(d3)); // 00:00:00
}
```

Comment: will this handle correctly daylight-saving switching? there are two such days every year

Comment: @ccpizza Not sure, if you're getting something wrong here. This is a duration, a duration does not care about daylight-saving time. If you start doing something at 1 am and at 2 am the clock jumps from 2 to 3 am, you still had one-hour duration of work.

Answer (score 37):

Just a quick implementation.

This will display the Duration in [DD]d:[HH]h:[mm]m:[ss]s format, and will ignore the leading element if it was 0. But seconds will always present.

For example:

1d:2h:3m:4s

2h:3m:4s

3m:4s

4s

0s

```
  /// Returns a formatted string for the given Duration [d] to be DD:HH:mm:ss
  /// and ignore if 0.
  static String formatDuration(Duration d) {
    var seconds = d.inSeconds;
    final days = seconds~/Duration.secondsPerDay;
    seconds -= days*Duration.secondsPerDay;
    final hours = seconds~/Duration.secondsPerHour;
    seconds -= hours*Duration.secondsPerHour;
    final minutes = seconds~/Duration.secondsPerMinute;
    seconds -= minutes*Duration.secondsPerMinute;

    final List<String> tokens = [];
    if (days != 0) {
      tokens.add('${days}d');
    }
    if (tokens.isNotEmpty || hours != 0){
      tokens.add('${hours}h');
    }
    if (tokens.isNotEmpty || minutes != 0) {
      tokens.add('${minutes}m');
    }
    tokens.add('${seconds}s');

    return tokens.join(':');
  }
```

Comment: I really like this implementation. I modified it a little bit to display `[[[DD:]hh:]mm]:ss` with zeros, such as "1:02:03" by replacing the add as `tokens.add(addZeroIfFirst(hours, tokens.isEmpty))` and `String addZeroIfFirst(int value, bool isFirst) {return sprintf((isFirst) ? "%d": "%02d", [value]);}`. This uses `sprintf` from https://pub.dev/packages/sprintf.

Answer (score 23):

Based on @diegoveloper's answer, I made it an extension which is also extendible

```
extension DurationExtensions on Duration {
  /// Converts the duration into a readable string
  /// 05:15
  String toHoursMinutes() {
    String twoDigitMinutes = _toTwoDigits(this.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    return "${_toTwoDigits(this.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes";
  }

  /// Converts the duration into a readable string
  /// 05:15:35
  String toHoursMinutesSeconds() {
    String twoDigitMinutes = _toTwoDigits(this.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = _toTwoDigits(this.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${_toTwoDigits(this.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

  String _toTwoDigits(int n) {
    if (n >= 10) return "$n";
    return "0$n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's another version.  It's all preference at this point, but I liked that it was dry and didn't need a function declaration (the wrapping function is obviously optional) though it is definately a bit function chaining heavy.

Compact

```dart
String formatTime(double time) {
    Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: time.round());
    return [duration.inHours, duration.inMinutes, duration.inSeconds].map((seg) => seg.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')).join(':');
}
```

Formatted version

```dart
String timeFormatter (double time) {
    Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: time.round());

    return [duration.inHours, duration.inMinutes, duration.inSeconds]
      .map((seg) => seg.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0'))
      .join(':');
}
```

Slightly longer, but accounts for hours > 60:

```dart
String timeFormatter (double time) {
    Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: time.round());

    return [duration.inHours, duration.inMinutes.remainder(60), duration.inSeconds.remainder(60)]
      .map((seg) => seg.toString().padLeft(2, '0'))
      .join(':');
}
```

Comment: Applying the remainder(60) to hours is problematic, since the Duration can be more than 24 hours. So after 60 hours, your display wraps back to 0 hours.

Comment: @ber Arguably at that point you might be wanting some other form of display, since we don't typically display times like 291:30:15.  But it is quirky behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Elaborating on other answers, here is an implementation that also formats days:

```
extension DurationFormatter on Duration {
  /// Returns a day, hour, minute, second string representation of this `Duration`.
  ///
  ///
  /// Returns a string with days, hours, minutes, and seconds in the
  /// following format: `dd:HH:MM:SS`. For example,
  ///
  ///   var d = new Duration(days:19, hours:22, minutes:33);
  ///    d.dayHourMinuteSecondFormatted();  // "19:22:33:00"
  String dayHourMinuteSecondFormatted() {
    this.toString();
    return [
      this.inDays,
      this.inHours.remainder(24),
      this.inMinutes.remainder(60),
      this.inSeconds.remainder(60)
    ].map((seg) {
      return seg.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    }).join(':');
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the `intl` package `DateFormat` class does not help: it marks the format of a `Duration` as not implemented:

```
formatDuration(DateTime reference) → String
NOT YET IMPLEMENTED. [...]
```

Answer (score 8):

Define this:

```dart
extension on Duration {
  String format() => '$this'.split('.')[0].padLeft(8, '0');
}
```

Usage:

```dart
String time = Duration(seconds: 3661).format(); // 01:01:01
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the easiest way

```
String get refactoredDuration{
    return Duration(seconds: duration).toString().split('.')[0];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```dart
print('${duration.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:
${duration.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:
${duration.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String myDuration(Duration duration) {
  var date = duration.toString().split(":");
  var hrs = date[0];
  var mns = date[1];
  var sds = date[2].split(".")[0];
  return "$hrs:$mns:$sds";
}
```

Comment: Seems a lot of work, when you could just split by `.`, which you end up doing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
final minuts = 83;
final show = DateFormat('H:mm').format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(minuts * 1000 * 60));
print(show);
```

output: 1:23

Comment: There are **16 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **two hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: This option supports localization. This is a different way of looking at the solution of the issue. He's a little prettier in my opinion. Please correct the formatting.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to help differentiate it from the existing answers? That comment is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer thinking of Millisecond as its own unit, rather than as a subunit of something else. In that sense, it will have values of 0-999, so you're going to want to Pad three instead of two like I have seen with other answers. Here is an implementation:

```
String format(Duration o) {
   var mil_s = (o.inMilliseconds % 1000).toString().padLeft(3, '0');
   var sec_s = (o.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
   return o.inMinutes.toString() + ' m ' + sec_s + ' s ' + mil_s + ' ms';
}
```

https://api.dart.dev/dart-core/Duration-class.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    extension on Duration {
      /// Returns a day, hour, minute, second string representation of this `Duration`.
      ///
      ///
      /// Returns a string with days, hours, minutes, and seconds in the
      /// following format: `dd:HH:MM:SS`. For example,
      ///
      ///   var d = new Duration(days:19, hours:22, minutes:33);
      ///    d.dayHourMinuteSecondFormatted();  // "19:22:33:00"
      String dayHourMinuteSecondFormatted() {
        toString();
        return [
          this.inDays,
          this.inHours.remainder(24),
          this.inMinutes.remainder(60),
          this.inSeconds.remainder(60)
        ].map((seg) {
          return seg.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
        }).join(':');
      }
    }



//use 
String result = Duration(seconds:102549).dayHourMinuteSecondFormatted();

//output: 
01:12:06:59----date:hour:minit:second
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 Text(RegExp(r'((^0*[1-9]\d*:)?\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+$')
      .firstMatch("$duration") ?.group(1) ?? '$duration'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the first so when hours are in 00 it will not show.

```
   extension VideoTimer on Duration {
  String format() {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(inSeconds.remainder(60));
    final hour = twoDigits(inHours);
    return "${hour == '00' ? '' : hour + ':'}$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
String _printDuration(Duration duration) {
String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
return "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
```

}

```
          Container( //duration of video
            child: Text("Total Duration: " + _printDuration(_controller.value.duration).toString()+" Position: " + _printDuration(_controller.value.position).toString()),
          ),
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)