# Display the difference between two Firestore Timestamp values in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am taking startdate and endDate as input from user with DateTime as datatype in Flutter(Dart). These fields will be stored in Firestore may be as timestamp format.
Now we need to display the difference of endDate and startDate on client side which can be a live timer in format as "13 Hrs 45 mins" then after some mins it should be "13 Hrs 42 mins".

May I know how can we achieve this using Firestore or may be cloud functions for Flutter apps?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter, `Timestamp` can be easily converted to `DateTime`, and `DateTime` has convenient method called `difference` that will give you difference between two `DateTime` objects as `Duration` object.

Here is a simple example:

```
final Timestamp endTime = Timestamp(1000, 0);
final Timestamp startTime = Timestamp(500, 0);
final DateTime endTimeDate = endTime.toDate();
final DateTime startTimeDate = startTime.toDate();
final Duration difference = endTimeDate.difference(startTimeDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am taking input in DateTime format as follows :-
selectedStartDate = 2021-01-03 10:41:00.000
selectedEndDate = 2021-01-05 16:41:00.000
And I am getting difference duration as : 54:00:00.000000

So my preferable output should be as 54 Hrs 00 mins. Can you please help here how to do this?

Comment: @Akshay You can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775097/formatting-a-duration-like-hhmmss